# HTTP Status 403 - Ajax Request Denied (Session Expired)

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

````
    console.log("AJAX CALL IN JS METHOD");
    var data="inputUserID="+"05102019";
     $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'AjaxHandler',
           data: data,
           success: function( data ) {
            alert("URL is correct");
           },
           error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              alert("URL is wrong");
           },
           dataType: 'text'
        });
   ```
````

HTTP Status 403 - Ajax Request Denied (Session Expired)
 type Status report
 message Ajax Request Denied (Session Expired)

description Access to the specified resource has been forbidden.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.64

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: what you are trying to do??